Connect PC to HVAC Router
I have a network with multiple Cisco 9300 Switches and 9606 Core switches. We had a PC connected directly to a Carrier i-Vu XT Router. The PC needs to be moved to another building. I connected the router to the switch for that building on VLAN 202. The switch connects directly to the core and to the other 9300 switch at the building where the PC was moved to. I have VLAN 202 on the trunks and on the access ports.
The IP address for the PC is 192.68.24.7 with default gateway 192.68.24.1.
On the switch where the router is connected I have the following setup for the VLAN interface port:
interface Vlan202
ip address 192.68.24.1 255.255.255.0
no ip redirects
no ip unreachables
no ip proxy-arp
ip ospf 1 area 0
no autostate
end

The interface configuration for the router and PC are the following:
switchport access vlan 202
 switchport mode access
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root

I did a show spanning-tree vlan 202 on both switches and the core with the following results:
Switch connected to the router:
MST0
  Spanning tree enabled protocol mstp
  Root ID    Priority    0
             Address     0000.0000.0080
             Cost        0
             Port        151 (TenGigabitEthernet2/1/3)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    8192   (priority 8192 sys-id-ext 0)
             Address     0000.0000.0010
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Te1/1/3             Altn BLK 20000     128.55   P2p   *Switch to Core 1*
Gi2/0/3             Desg FWD 20000     128.99   P2p Edge *HVAC router*
Te2/1/3             Root FWD 20000     128.151  P2p *Switch to Core 2*

Switch connected to PC:
MST0
  Spanning tree enabled protocol mstp
  Root ID    Priority    0
             Address     0000.0000.0080
             Cost        0
             Port        49 (GigabitEthernet1/1/1)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    53248  (priority 53248 sys-id-ext 0)
             Address     0000.0000.1b00
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Gi1/0/15            Desg FWD 2000000   128.15   P2p Edge *PC*
Gi1/1/1             Root FWD 20000     128.49   P2p *Trunk to Switch connected to Router*

Core Router 1:
MST0
  Spanning tree enabled protocol mstp
  Root ID    Priority    0
             Address     0000.0000.0080
             Cost        0
             Port        2089 (Port-channel1)
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

  Bridge ID  Priority    4096   (priority 4096 sys-id-ext 0)
             Address     0000.0000.0300
             Hello Time   2 sec  Max Age 20 sec  Forward Delay 15 sec

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Twe1/0/1            Desg FWD 20000     128.1    P2p *Trunk to HVAC Switch*
Twe2/0/7            Desg FWD 20000     128.103  P2p *Trunk to PC Switch*
Po1                 Root FWD 1000      128.2089 P2p *Trunk to Core 2*

I am able to ping the router from anywhere in the network except from the PC. I know that the ports that need to be open are UDP 47808 and TCP Ports 80 and 443.
Not sure what other configuration I need to let the PC communicate with the router.

Is vlan 202 configured on the switch in the other building?

The vlan 202 exists in the building where the PC is, but not the interface vlan 202.

run show spanning-tree vlan 202 on all the switches and verify that the PC, router and trunk ports are all in  forwarding mode.  Please edit your question to include that info.

I ran the command all 3 switches. On the switch where the router is connected, the router port is Desg, trunk port to the core is Altn, and the root is set to the other core switch. On the switch where the PC is located the PC's interface is Desg, the trunk port to the core is set as root. On the Core switch the trunk  ports to the HVAC is set as Desg, and the Port channel is root.

Do you see a mac address on the port connected to the PC? sh mac address | inc Gix/0/y

@RonTrunk yes, but nothing if I do a sh ip arp with its MAC Address. Not even on the core switch.

Do you see the mac address on the core switch? `sh mac address | inc xxxx.yyyy.zzzz'

@RonTrunk Yes, I can see it from the Core switch. 202    0000.0000.007d    DYNAMIC     Twe2/0/7

It seems that layer 2 is working properly.  So now I'm suspicious of the PC configuration.  Are you sure it has the proper gateway configured?

@RonTrunk The DG on the PC is set to 192.68.24.1, But I can't ping that from there. Everywhere else I can ping it.

Do you see the mac address of the pc on the switch with the dg?

@RonTrunk I can see both MAC addresses from the switches connected to both HVAC router and PC from their respective interface ports.

You see the PC MAC address on the gateway switch.  This tells me that the switches are forwarding frames correctly.  But you don't see an ARP entry.  That suggests the PC is sending a bad (address) ARP request.  If it were correct, the switch would have an ARP entry.  Is there another PC you can try?

I've tested setting another port on both switches and connecting a laptop on the same subnet. Tried to ping each other from both locations, but failed. We connected together to test that they could ping and Windows Firewall wouldn't be an issue. The communicate fine within the switch, but no communication going out.
